# What does __modti3 do?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

Recently, I tried to write a program to compute (a * b) % m where (0<=a, b, m<=2^63-1). And, fortunately, I know that GCC support `__int128_t`. So I end up with the following program.

```
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t multimod(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t m)
{
  __int128_t ab = (__int128_t)a * b;
  ab %= m;
  return ab;
}
```

But I want to do this without `__int128_t` in order to both challenge myself and make this function more efficient. I decided to do this by first simulating the process of the assembly program of this function. So I used `objdump` and get the following part of `multimod`.

```
int64_t multimod(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t m)
{
 720:   55                      push   %rbp
 721:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9 
 724:   49 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%r8
 727:   49 c1 f8 3f             sar    $0x3f,%r8
 72b:   48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
 72e:   48 c1 f8 3f             sar    $0x3f,%rax
 732:   4c 89 c2                mov    %r8,%rdx
 735:   48 0f af d6             imul   %rsi,%rdx
 739:   48 0f af c7             imul   %rdi,%rax
 73d:   49 89 c0                mov    %rax,%r8 
 740:   49 01 d0                add    %rdx,%r8 
 743:   48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
 746:   48 f7 e6                mul    %rsi
 749:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 74c:   49 8d 34 10             lea    (%r8,%rdx,1),%rsi
 750:   4c 89 c9                mov    %r9,%rcx
 753:   48 c1 f9 3f             sar    $0x3f,%rcx
 757:   4c 89 ca                mov    %r9,%rdx
 75a:   e8 61 00 00 00          callq  7c0 <__modti3>
 75f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 760:   c3                      retq
```

I analysed the whole part and believe that it can be divided into two parts --- 1. get the right 128-bit product of 64-bit variable `a` and `b` 2. `__modti3`.

I STFW and got to know that the prototype of `__modti3` is `long long __modti3(long long a, long long b)`. But the assembly code does not get it this way. When it call `__modti3`, the first argument `%rdi` contains low 64-bit of product of `a` and `b`, the second argument `%rsi` containing hign 64-bit of product of `a` and `b`, the third argument `%rdx` containing `m`. So what did `__modti3` do to get the answer right?

Comment: "the commented part is some other experiments" Then you might remove it from the question, don't you?

Comment: From the code I believe `modti3` takes two 128 bit operands split in halves.

Comment: @Jester Yes, that is exactly why it is so confusing! Both the manual and web show that it takes two `long long` arguments but it seems not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `long long` is 64-bit. You can see gcc is passing __modti3 args in rdi, rsi, rdx, and rcx. (i.e. the first 4 arg-passing slots in the x86-64 SysV ABI.)

So that's two 128-bit operands, passed by value in pairs of regs: `rsi:rdi` and `rcx:rdx`.

**It's actually `__int128 __modti3(__int128 quotient, __int128 divisor);`** That's the whole point and reason for existence: x86-64 has `long long % long long` remainder in hardware with
`idiv r64`, which gcc will use for runtime-variable divisors / moduli.

---

Notice that your function is sign-extending `m` from `rdx` into `rcx:rdx` with

```
mov    %r9, %rcx        # originally from RDX on entry; you didn't enable full optimization
sar    $63, %rcx        # copy sign bit to all bit positions.
```

This is exactly like what `cqo` (AT&T `cqto`) does to sign-extend RAX into RDX:RAX.

---

BTW, the code is easier to read if you enable full optimization with `-O3`.  Then you only get 1 multiply instruction, using 64-bit inputs and producing a 128-bit output.  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/0gKc5d

Compiling with `-O1` or `-Og` is sometimes more helpful if you want asm that looks more like the source, but since C doesn't have a widening-multiply operator, you don't actually want that.  You *want* the compiler to optimize widening the inputs before multiplying into a widening multiply, instead of sign-extending the inputs into pairs of registers and doing a 128x128 => 128-bit multiply.  (Which is what's happening in the code you show.)

Comment: So actually the prototype of `__modit3` should be `__int128 __modit3(__int128, __int128)` and the compiler will pass `__int128` by passing a pair of regs?

Comment: @RiversShall: Yes.